# Send and Receive Data Between Flash & .Net

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling ActionScript 3 function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472234/calling-actionscript-3-function-from-c-sharp)

i have a project which is is a desktop application in .Net, and from .Net 3 String value is Passed to Flash.
My question is how to receive data coming from the desktop application in flash as3?
because here i don't have any URL to load data.

Anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Well the desktop application and the Flash application should have a shared data source. A database + web service, an XML file or perhaps a shared network location.

Comment: What project do you have on C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you should consider [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6):

- http://blog.another-d-mention.ro/programming/communicate-betwen-c-and-an-embeded-flash-application/
- [Calling ActionScript 3 function from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472234/calling-actionscript-3-function-from-c-sharp)