# C# / ActionScript with AxShockwaveFlash

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, apache-flex, axshockwaveflash

I am new to ActionScript and am trying to communicate between AS and C#. Every tutorial/explanation I find seems to be exactly the same, but I simply cannot get it to work. `callFunction` throws a COM exception ("E_FAIL"), and when I try calling `ExternalInterface.call()` from the AS, it never seems to.

I've gotten this to work in JavaScript/HTML, but I'm out of ideas for C#; I suspect I'm doing something wrong/not allowed in my AS. I compile the AS file with Adobe Flex 4.6 and mxmlc.

Edit: Just to clarify, this code shows only the test with calling a C# function from AS since it seems less error-prone (no xml argument handling needed). Also, I've run a test with a `while(true) ExternalInterface.call("someFct", "Hello world");` loop in my AS and my CPU usage for the debug process is basically the same as with no instructions in the AS (~0.3%). So it seems the code doesn't execute at all.

Here is my AS file:

```
package
{
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    public class Test
    {     
        public function Test()
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("someFct", "Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

And in C# I have an AxShockwaveFlash control in WinForms:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
    this.axShockwaveFlash1 = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axShockwaveFlash1)).BeginInit();
    this.SuspendLayout();
    // 
    // axShockwaveFlash1
    // 
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.Enabled = true;
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(104, 67);
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.Name = "axShockwaveFlash1";
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axShockwaveFlash1.OcxState")));
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(574, 314);
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.axShockwaveFlash1.FlashCall += new AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEventHandler(this.recv);
    this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Click);
//...
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.axShockwaveFlash1)).EndInit();
     this.ResumeLayout(false);
}
```

Initializing the SWF object and receiving its call:

```
private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, @"mypath\test.swf");
}

//Never executes
public void recv(object sender, _IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEvent e)
{
    string s = e.request;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problems.

1) As I suspected, the COM object needs some kind of graphic initialization in order to work at all. Making your main class extend `Sprite` solves this.

2) You apparently can't use `ExternalInterface.call()` or `ExternalInterface.setCallback()` in the main class' constructor directly. Creating an instance of a new class in the main class' constructor and making the `ExternalInterface` call in its constructor or any other function solves this.

Test.as:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    public class Test extends Sprite
    {     
        public function Test()
        {
            super();
            var x : Test1 = new Test1();
        }
    }
}
```

And Test1.as:

```
package
{   
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
    public class Test1
    {
        public function Test1()
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("recv", "Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

I also have *no* idea why someone would downvote my question...